# Adding dynamic elements, and setting their width/height in a separate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, underscore.js

I'm creating a (parent) `<section class="slide-item" data-id="slide-1">` element for each group of (child) items returned from a `jsonp` request. Each group is an object within an array:

```
array[ object, object, object ]
```

Each object contains attributes like the name, id, and, most importantly a nested array of `<img />` elements that I'm appending to the corresponding `<section>` — the DOM looks something like this

```
   <section class="slide-item" data-id="slide-1">
       <img src="http://lh5.ggpht.com/ySlk_p3UhTdXWyKXv=s1200" /> 
       <img src="http://lh5.ggpht.com/ySlk_p3UhTdXWyKXv=s1200" />
       <img src="http://lh5.ggpht.com/ySlk_p3UhTdXWyKXv=s1200" />
   </section>
```

Ideally, what I would like to do is to create/add the DOM with one function, and then have another function that handles adding the width, height, and any other pertinent size/layout information.

I know I can achieve it this way:

```
      module.draft = function () {

        _.each( GROUP, function( id ) {

            BUILD.push( '<section class="slide-item" style="width:' + widthVar + ';"></section>' );

        });

        parentElement.append( BUILD.join( '' ) );

        }
```

However,

I would like to wait until the DOM is loaded, and then apply width height:

```
      module.draft = function () {

        _.each( GROUP, function( id ) {

            BUILD.push( '<section class="slide-item"></section>' );

        });

        parentElement.append( BUILD.join( '' ) );

        };

 module.architect = function () { <--- Doesn't work

   parentElement
      .find( '.slide-item' )
      .width( widthVar )
      .height( heightVar );

   // # Other sizing stuff

   };
```

**EDIT**

A little more information: `GROUP` is the initial array of objects I mention in the beginning of the question: `array[ object, object, object ]` ,  `BUILD` is an empty array.

I'm calling the functions like this:

```
  module.init = function() {
        module.draft();
        module.architect();
    }
```

and then `$( document ).on( 'ready', _app.init );`

Also, I know I can make this work with `$( window ).on( 'load', _app.init );` but, it's not ideal.

Comment: I think we need to see the missing code to understand the problem better. For instance, when is "module.draft" function being called? In your question we can see the declaration, but not the execution of the function. Same thing happens with "module.architect". Also, who are BUILD and GROUP? Having this information could help us to figure out your problem better, thus being able to reply.

Comment: @Romen, Thanks for taking a look. Both `draft` and `architect` are being called in an `init` function on `$( document ).on( 'ready', init );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried it in JsFiddle and I thnik that the following solution does what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/99Pnu/12/

**Explanation**

First of all I'm declaring the variables to be used:

```
/* vars */
GROUP = [
    {id: 1, img: '<img src="http://testimage1.png" />'},
    {id: 2, img: '<img src="http://testimage2.png" />'},
    {id: 3, img: '<img src="http://testimage3.png" />'}
];
BUILD = [];
module = {};

widthVar = 200;
heightVar = 250;
```

The I have the init function and the "draft" and "architect" functions too

```
/* init */
module.init = function() {
    $parentElement = $("body");
    module.draft();
    module.architect();
}

/* functions */
module.draft = function () {
    _.each( GROUP, function( id ) {
        BUILD.push( '<section class="slide-item"></section>' );
    });
    $parentElement.append( BUILD.join( '' ) );
};

module.architect = function () {
    $parentElement
      .find( '.slide-item' )
      .width( widthVar )
      .height( heightVar );
    // # Other sizing stuff
};
```

Finally we have the "on ready" statement at the bottom:

```
$( document ).on( 'ready', module.init );
```

---

Does this solve your problem?

I have been debugging and it seems to work. The draft function creates the "section" DOM elements and the architect function sets their width and height.

I hope this helps you.
Regards, Romén.

Comment: Thanks Romen, that does indeed work, it's not the exact solution I was looking for, but it's given me a couple of ideas.